# Access Forbidden XAMPP

Tags: apache, xampp

Ok so I've been having some trouble accessing a subfolder inside a project folder. I have the following structure:

```
-htdocs
    -Project
        -admin
```

The problem I'm havin is when I type `localhost:8080/Project/admin` (I changed the apache port to 8080) I get the `Access Forbidden!` error. I've read about the "New security concept" and tried to comment out the `Require local` line in the `httpd-xampp.conf`but still have no luck. Does anyone know how to solve this? Thanks in advanced!

Comment: Looks like you cross-posted this on Stack Overflow [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35328831/access-forbidden-xampp). Since it doesn't involve programming, it's likely a better fit here. I'd suggest flagging it there to let a moderator know, or just delete it (to avoid possible comments or downvotes there...).

Comment: what version of XAMPP are you using? Can you also include the version of Apache

Answer (score 1):

Hm... try to put this code into your host file.

```
<Directory "/path/to/your/dir">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride all
        Order Deny,Allow
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```